# Painter Shape over QIcon in PySide

Tags: python, pyside

How can I append a painted rectangle to a QIcon. The final returned result has to be a qicon because I'm using this on a control which expects a qicon.

**Before**:

[image]

**After**:

[image]

```
import os, sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.resize(600,400)

        self.btn = QtGui.QPushButton()
        self.btn.setFixedSize(128,128)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon('thumb.jpg')
        self.btn.setIconSize(icon.availableSizes()[0])
        self.btn.setIcon(icon)

        lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        lay.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.setLayout(lay)


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read the image as `QPixmap`, use `QPainter` to modify the `QPixmap` by adding the rectangle and finally use the `QPixmap` to create the `QIcon`

```
import sys

from PySide import QtCore, QtGui


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.resize(600,400)

        lay = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)

        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap('thumb.jpg')
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(pixmap)
        painter.fillRect(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 40, 40), QtGui.QColor("red"))
        painter.end()

        for icon in (QtGui.QIcon('thumb.jpg'), QtGui.QIcon(pixmap)):
            btn = QtGui.QPushButton()
            btn.setFixedSize(128,128)
            btn.setIconSize(icon.availableSizes()[0])
            btn.setIcon(icon)
            lay.addWidget(btn)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]